# Testing a React Provider wrapped component with useReducer using Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have been struggling for a couple of days with testing a component that is wrapped in a provider which value is taken from the components `useReducer` reducer.

At the moment I am calling the reducer as the value to
`<NavUpdateDispatchContext.Provider value={useNavDispatch()}>`

The trouble is this doesn't work as I can't use `useReducer` outside of the component?

Does anyone know of a way around this?

This is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-firefly-3gqyz

The test is in `src/SignOut/__tests__/SignOut-test.tsx`

The error I am getting is:

> Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called
>   inside of the body of a function component.

Apologies the sandbox doesn't render as it requires firebase, but I thought the code is probably enough?

Thanks so much

To save visiting the codesandbox:

```
//Current test: /src/SignOut/__tests__/SignOut-test.tsx
test('renders a Sign Out button', () => {
  render(
    <NavUpdateDispatchContext.Provider value={useNavDispatch()}>
      <NavStatusContext.Provider value={{ navIsOpen: false }}>
        <SignOut />
      </NavStatusContext.Provider>
    </NavUpdateDispatchContext.Provider>,
  )
})

// Sign out: /src/SignOut/index.tsx
interface P {
  firebase: firebase.app.App
}

const SignOut = ({ firebase }: P) => {
  const dispatch = useNavDispatch()

  return (
    <LinkButton
      onClick={() => {
        firebase
          .auth()
          .signOut()
          .then(() => dispatch({ type: 'close' }))
      }}
    >
      SignOut
    </LinkButton>
  )
}

// Nav Reducer in /src/Header/index.tsx
const navReducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'open': {
      return { navIsOpen: true }
    }
    case 'close': {
      return { navIsOpen: false }
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type in navReducer: ${action!.type}`)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you render `Header` in your tests so you don't have to mock the context.

Comment: Thanks Giorgio, I tried that, but Header has a Router dependency, as Router is defined in thew uppermost component: `App`

Comment: Not a problem, warp `Header` in a router. See [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router)

Comment: Very nice, thanks so much! I am getting a TS error though, ui has type `any`. What type is this? A React Component?

Comment: I think it should be `React.ReactNode`. I'm not 100% sure because I don't use TS for tests

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you, but the test fails, as Header loads a nav component based on the auth status. As there is no user being passed - the unauthenticated nav is being returned so there is no SignOut link. In this case, would it be better under the original implementation?

Comment: I did manage to get it working by adjusting the reducer value passed to the Dispatch value: `useNavDispatch` as opposed to `useNavDispatch()`

Comment: I also am unsure of the validity of what exactly to test in the SignOut component. It is purely a button which on click calls firebase.

Comment: Sorry - just realised I made a simplified version of my Nav to get the codesandbox setup, I have now added the actual Nav component in the sandbox under /src/Navigation/auth-nav.tsx